Google Drive putting files in spam folder
(This has nothing to do with email spam.)
Drive Spam folder was introduced May 2023, in drive it's just under the bin.
https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2023/05/google-drive-spam-folder.html
I'm writing an Apps Script backup solution.

UserA (domain user) copies files into a staging folder (under My Drive) and adds UserB (external Gmail account) as a viewer.
UserB reads the staging folder and copies the files to a separate location.

This worked well for months, but recently files disappear.

UserA copies 5 files into a folder & can see 5 files, but UserB can only see 3 files.
After hours of head scratching I finally found loads of files under UserB's Spam folder within Drive (nothing to do with email).

Taking the ID of a file in the spam folder, it does not appear listed as in it's own parent folder.  Also, the spam folder has URL:
https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/spam, so I can't open & search it by code.
For most files, this code lists the files (including itself) in the same folder. For files in spam, this code doesn't work.
function proveMad(){
  var fileID= "<Big long ID string>";
  var myFile = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);
  var parents = myFile.getParents();
  var parentFolder=parents.next();
  console.log(`Parent Folder ID is ${parentFolder}`);
  var files = parentFolder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    file = files.next();
    console.log(`FileID: ${file.getId()}, Name: ${file.getName()}`);
  } 
}

Via API, can I trawl spam folder and find any files which were originally under my staging folder?

Please reword the post to clearly state one specific question that is unique to programming.
